# Linux - Monitor cumulated focus time of a window or application since it started

Tags: linux, focus

I'm using Debian Wheezy (with xfce) and I would like to know if there is an easy way (meaning not so much programming / easy setup, ideally an already existing package) to monitor the cumulated time a certain window or application has had focus since it has been running.

I am using an instant messaging program and I want to find out, at the end of each day (or at a given time), for how long the application received focus til it was launched, so that I can know how long I've spent reading / writing on IM (and not doing something else).

I've searched on Google and Stackoverflow and I found a few things about XQueryTree, xlib, XGetInputFocus but most of the time, it was pieces of C code, which I could not really use because I have a almost no knowledge of C (I do a bit of programming for the web, bash scripting though).

If some basic programming in C is really required to get there, and if there's no existing package / program that does that, I'd be more than happy to give it a try and to learn, but then I'd like to ask you guys for some directions (like where to start, how to organize the code and so on).

Thank you in advance.